# Change element size using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I have following code in my component

```
var rect = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
```

I use [d3js](https://d3js.org/) and render graph in the component. But when I run test there are any **svg** tags. I assume that it happens because all **rect's** fields equals 0.

Here is output for *console.log(rect)* in browser:

> ClientRect {top: 89, right: 808, bottom: 689, left: 8, width: 800…}

and when I run test:

> { bottom: 0, height: 0, left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, width: 0 }

So is there a way to set size of the element?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

My solution is to mock `getBoundingClientRect`
(I'm currently using jest 16.0.1)

```html
describe('Mock `getBoundingClientRect`', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = jest.fn(() => {
            return {
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                right: 0,
            }
        });
    });
    it('should mock `getBoundingClientRect`', () => {
        const element = document.createElement('span');
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        expect(rect.width).toEqual(120);
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just wondering, where is the "Element" came from?

Comment: @WayneChiu AFAIK, jest uses jsdom to mock DOM classes (such as Element, etc) - https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Comment: N.B. If you have multiple describes that have specific cases for getBoundingClientRect, you'll need to set this mock again for that particular describe, since the global objects prototype is being mutated

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to put the original value of `getBoundingClientRect` back, because changing it might affect other tests.

Also, no need to do it in `beforeEach`: `beforeAll` will do.

```js
describe("Mock `getBoundingClientRect`", () => {
  let boundingClientRect;

  const originalGetBoundingClientRect = Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect;

  beforeAll(() => {
    Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = () => boundingClientRect;
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = originalGetBoundingClientRect;
  });

  it("should mock `getBoundingClientRect`", () => {
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    boundingClientRect = new DOMRect(0, 0, 120, 120);
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    expect(rect.width).toEqual(120);
  });
});
```

I took the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62904193/442553)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers mock `Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect`. This will affect the apparent size of *all* DOM elements in your tests.

If you know what element you care about in advance, you can mock `getBoundingClientRect` on a single element. This does not affect the apparent size of other elements. If you want two elements to have different sizes in the same test, this is the way you need to do it.

```js
describe("Mock `getBoundingClientRect` on a single element", () => {
  it("should mock `getBoundingClientRect`", () => {
    const myElement = document.createElement("div");
    myElement.getBoundingClientRect = jest.fn(() => 
      new DOMRect(0, 0, 120, 120);
    );
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    expect(rect.width).toEqual(120);
  });
});
```