# React Ref's offsetheight, always returns '0' for jest test case even after the content is loaded

Tags: reactjs, dom, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using **react-testing-library** and **jest**. In componentdidupdate trying to get '**this.testRef.current.offsetHeight**', getting offsetHeight as **0** even after content is loaded. I want DOM's exact offsetHeight because of having some conditions based on it.

Is there any possible solution to resolve in react-testing-library and jest.

I am using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** to binding html content for testRef's element.

Comment: Jest doesn't render the DOM so the element doesn't really exist (so it can't have a height.) You have to mock such values.

Comment: @JJJ As am new to this, I tried to mock data using jest.spyOn(). I don't know how to mock createRef get function for that component?

import MyCompont from 'components/mycomponent';

I need MyCompont's ref's offsetHeight value.

Can you provide me example?

I tried using this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721999/react-jest-enzyme-how-to-mock-ref-properties). I did't use enzyme here.

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like this :

```
  const originalOffsetHeight = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    HTMLElement.prototype,
    'offsetHeight'
  );
  const originalOffsetWidth = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth');
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight', {
      configurable: true,
      value: 200,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', { 
      configurable: true, value: 200 
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight', originalOffsetHeight);
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', originalOffsetWidth);
  });
```

Comment: This sets the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` values of all the elements in the test to. Is there a way this method can target a specific element?

Comment: @Avi either use 2 different elements to make the comparison and use `HTMLDivElement.prototype` and `HTMLSpanElement.prototype` for example, or use a `jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockImplementationOnce` to match each time ref will be returned and defined the property in a div or span element created inside the mock, which is complicated. I used a Div trimmed and inside a Span with inline display to test a ShowMoreText component.